# How to speed up AStar?

Tags: java, 2d, path-finding

I have this AStar class, and at the movement it is INCREDIBLY slow.  It takes waaay longer than I expected it too, and I'm not quite sure why.  I added the generation part at the very beginning to speed it up somewhat, and all though it helped my game takes like 15 seconds to load.

If this isn't the right place to ask how to speed it up, just let me know.  I'm not sure if this is too "debug my code" esq.

Thanks everyone! - tips

```
public class AStar {
    private final Tank tank;

    private Map<String, Node> nodes;

    public AStar(Tank tank) {
        this.tank = tank;

        this.nodes = new HashMap<String, Node>();
    }

    public void generate() {
        //long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < TanksWorld.MAX_X; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < TanksWorld.MAX_Y; j++) {
                Node node = new Node(i, j);
                nodes.put(node.hash(), node);
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("Generate took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now));
    }

    public void reset() {
       // long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (Node node : nodes.values()) {
            node.reset();
        }
        //System.out.println("Reset took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now));
    }

    public Path pathTo(int xFinish, int yFinish) {
        int xStart = tank.getFloorX();
        int yStart = tank.getFloorY();

        if (xStart == xFinish && yStart == yFinish) {
            return new Path(true);
        }

        Node startNode = get(xStart, yStart);
        Node goalNode = get(xFinish, yFinish);

        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
        queue.add(startNode);

        Path bestPath = null;

        while (queue.size() != 0) {
            Node current = queue.poll();
            int xCurrent = current.getX();
            int yCurrent = current.getY();
            if (current.visited) {
                continue;
            }
            if (current.equals(goalNode)) {
                bestPath = reconstruct(current);
                break;
            }
            addNeighbors(current);
            current.visited = true;

            for (Node node : current.getNeighbors()) {
                if (node == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (node.visited) {
                    continue;
                }
                int xNode = node.getX();
                int yNode = node.getY();
                double distance = current.pathDistance + TanksGame.distance(xCurrent, yCurrent, xNode, yNode); // TODO distance
                if (node.parent != null && distance >= node.pathDistance) {
                    continue;
                }
                node.pathDistance = distance;
                node.heuristicDistance = TanksGame.distance(xNode, yNode, xFinish, yFinish) + distance;
                if (node.parent == null) {
                    node.priority = node.heuristicDistance;
                    queue.add(node);
                } else {
                    node.priority = node.heuristicDistance;
                }
                node.parent = current;
            }
        }

        return bestPath == null ? new Path(false) : bestPath;

    }

    private void addNeighbors(Node node) {
        int startX = node.getX();
        int startY = node.getY();

        // up
        node.addNeighbor(get(startX + Tank.MVMT_SPEED, startY));
        // down
        node.addNeighbor(get(startX, startY - Tank.MVMT_SPEED));
        // left
        node.addNeighbor(get(startX - Tank.MVMT_SPEED, startY));
        // right
        node.addNeighbor(get(startX + Tank.MVMT_SPEED, startY));
        // up left
        node.addNeighbor(get(startX - Tank.MVMT_SPEED, startY + Tank.MVMT_SPEED));
        // up right
        node.addNeighbor(get(startX + Tank.MVMT_SPEED, startY + Tank.MVMT_SPEED));
        // down left
        node.addNeighbor(get(startX - Tank.MVMT_SPEED, startY - Tank.MVMT_SPEED));
        // down right
        node.addNeighbor(get(startX + Tank.MVMT_SPEED, startY - Tank.MVMT_SPEED));
    }

    private Path reconstruct(Node goalNode) {
        Path path = new Path(true);
        Node node = goalNode;
        while (node != null) {
            path.addToFront(node);
            node = node.parent;
        }
        return path;
    }

    private Node get(int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (y < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (x > TanksWorld.MAX_X) {
            return null;
        }
        if (y > TanksWorld.MAX_Y) {
            return null;
        }
        String hash = Node.hash(x, y);
        return nodes.get(hash);
    }

    public class Path {
        private boolean finished;
        private List<Node> path;
        private int index;

        public Path(boolean finished) {
            this.finished = finished;
            this.index = 0;
            this.path = new ArrayList<Node>();
        }

        public boolean isFinished() {
            return finished;
        }

        public void addToFront(Node node) {
            path.add(0, node);
        }

        public Node get() {
            return path.get(index);
        }

        public void next() {
            index++;
        }

        public int getSize() {
            return path.size();
        }

        public boolean isDone() {
            return index >= getSize();
        }
    }

    public static class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
        private final int x;
        private final int y;

        private List<Node> neighbors;

        // TODO getters and setters
        public boolean visited = false;
        public double pathDistance = 0;
        public double heuristicDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        public Node parent = null;
        public double priority = 0;

        public Node(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.neighbors = new ArrayList<Node>();
        }

        public void reset() {
            parent = null;
            priority = 0;
            heuristicDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            pathDistance = 0;
            visited = false;
        }

        public List<Node> getNeighbors() {
            return neighbors;
        }

        public void addNeighbor(Node node) {
            neighbors.add(node);
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public int compare(Node one, Node two) {
            if (one.priority == two.priority) {
                return 0;
            }
            return one.priority > two.priority ? 1 : -1;
        }

        public int compareTo(Node two) {
            return compare(this, two);
        }

        public static String hash(int x, int y) {
            return "x_" + x + "_y_" + y + "_";
        }

        public String hash() {
            return "x_" + x + "_y_" + y + "_";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Tips, yeah, it's pretty much "debug my code". I suggest you get yourself a profiler. The profiler will show you exactly which parts of your code are taking the longest. It could be not in your pathfinding code, but how you're using the pathfinding code (i.e. finding lots and lots of paths). I know Netbeans has one built in that's pretty nice, [give it a try](https://netbeans.org/downloads/).

Comment: The following journal article provides a concise but detailed descriptions of optimizations of Djikstra's algorithm. Note that a* is one of these. Bidirectional Djikstra is another, and you can use both in tandem. http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/documents/routeplanning/geisberger_dipl.pdf

Comment: Also, check for any casts between integer types and float types in your deeply-nested loops. Integer arithmetic is faster than floating point in general, but converting back and forth is a real performance killer.

Comment: There are several ways to improve a good but primitive A* algorithm. I suggest reading into hierarchical A*, quad tree's and binary heaps. Basically you want to iterate to the least possible amount of nodes when you require a new path. Hierarchical path-finding splits the map up in larger chunks where quad tree's and binary heaps help you directly with iterating through the least amount of nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, your node `priority` should be based on the total estimated distance from start to end: `current.pathDistance + node.heuristicDistance`. You want to pick the nodes that have best likely outcome.

For two, the [priorityQueue documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) reads `The head of this queue is the least element`, which means that your compare will want to return smaller values for more desirable choices, a subtraction should suffice: `one.priority - two.priority`

Before these changes, your algorithm was selecting nodes that were furthest from the destination to calculate next, which would result in flood-filling the entire world before settling on a result. That could take a while, especially if you re-calculate the "shortest" distance to every node from every adjacent node.

Comment: Even though it may look like I'm picking holes, I'd like to note that your code was very clean and easy to read. Well done.

Comment: No, that's fine.  Thank you very much, I'll try all of these and see how it works!

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant on the second paragraph? That first part helped a lot.

Comment: I believe the code under the `Node.compare` is returning the worse node as a better option (the opposite of what you want). If `one` is smaller than `two`, it should return -1, else return 1.